# In Swift Table View not populating Firebase data

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've been stuck with this issue for the past 2 days and can't find a solution. I'm using Firebase with a View Controller, top portion of the screen I'm using it to display the info of the user that is logged in and under I have a Table View where I want to display the picture and basic information of other users. I'm able to download the data from Firebase and display the info of the user that is logged-in. The issue I'm having is populating the data inside the cells. I created a service file because I'm going to use the functions few times in other areas of the app.

Here is my code:

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

struct Service {
    
    static func fetchUser(withUid uid: String, completion: @escaping(Member) -> Void) {
        COLLECTION_USERS.document(uid).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in
            guard let dictionary = snapshot?.data() else { return }
            let user = Member(dictionary: dictionary)
            completion(user)}
    }
    
    static func fetchUsers(forCurrentUser user: Member, completion: @escaping([Member]) -> Void) {
        var members = [Member]()
        
        let query = COLLECTION_USERS
        
        query.getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
            guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
            snapshot.documents.forEach({ document in
                let dictionary = document.data()
                let user = Member(dictionary: dictionary)
                                        
                guard user.uid != Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
                members.append(user)
                                        
                    if members.count == snapshot.documents.count - 1 { completion(members)
                        print("FROM SERVICE MEMBERS: \(members)") // Console displays this: FROM SERVICE FETCHING USERS COUNT 5
                }}
            )}
    }
}
```

**VIEW CONTROLLER**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class HomeVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
   
    @IBOutlet weak var memberFeedTableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileImage: userImagesView!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileNameAgeLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileCityLbl: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var profileStatus: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var changeFilterOptions: UIBarButtonItem!

    var members = [Member]()
    
    var userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    var handle: AuthStateDidChangeListenerHandle?
    var userListener: ListenerRegistration!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        memberFeedTableView.dataSource = self
        memberFeedTableView.delegate = self
        memberFeedTableView.rowHeight = 450
        
        configureUI()
        
        fetchUserData()
    }
        
    func configureUI() {
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
        overrideUserInterfaceStyle = .light
        
        tapToReleaseKeyboard()
        
        let background = backgroundGradientColor()
        background.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.layer.insertSublayer(background, at: 0)
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return members.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = memberFeedTableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MembersFeedCell", for: indexPath) as! MembersFeedCell
        cell.configureMemberFeedCell(member: members[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
    
    func fetchUsersData(forCurrentUser user: Member) {
        Service.fetchUsers(forCurrentUser: user) { users in
            self.members = users //issue is here, I'm not sure how to send the array to the table view to populate the cells.
            print("CHECKING ARRAY..: \(self.members.count)") // Console displays this: CHECKING ARRAY..: 4



        }
    }
    
    func fetchUserData() {
        guard let currentUid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
        Service.fetchUser(withUid: currentUid) { user in
            self.fetchUsersData(forCurrentUser: user)
            self.profileNameAgeLbl.text = user.name + "," + " " + (user.age)
            self.profileCityLbl.text = user.city
            self.profileImage.loadImage(with: user.imageURL)}
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Just call `memberFeedTableView.reloadData()`